# CoreData and CloudKit Sync works, but NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange notification never fires

Tags: swift, core-data, push-notification, notifications, cloudkit

I've updated an existing CoreData app to use CloudKit so that it can keep data synchronised across multiple devices (for the same iCloud account).

It works!  The data sync's just fine.

But the primary UIViewController's view does not reflect the new data.  To see the changes, I have to switch to a different view, then switch back to the primary view which has a `refreshData()` call in its `viewWillAppear()` function.  It then re-reads from the data store and displays all the data (including whatever was updated on some other device.

The UIViewController should be observing the `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange` notification as per the `viewDidLoad()` below:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    //  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRemoteChange), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: AppDelegate.appDelegate().persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRemoteChange), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: nil)
    }
```

But the handler function never gets called:

```swift
    @objc func handleRemoteChange(notification: Notification) {
        print("Handling remote change to data in Collection Controller")
        refreshData()
    }
```

That print statement never prints anything, and a breakpoint set there never fires.

I have configured the managed object context to merge changes from parent as required immediately after the `NSPersistentCloutKitContainer` is created:

```swift
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

The application has all the relevant iCloud capabilities and entitlements that I'm aware of after scouring the web (and Stack Overflow) for clues, including:

- "Remote notifications" (Background Modes)
- "CloudKit" (iCloud)
- A container has been created and selected with an identifier of the
  format:  iCloud.reverse.domain.app

The Container's persistentStoreDescription has the `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey` option set to true:

```swift
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("FAILED to load persistent store:\(storeDescription)\nERROR:\n\(error)\n\(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })

        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        for description in container.persistentStoreDescriptions {
            description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        }
```

Clearly the data is being sync'd OK.  It's just the notification that is not working as expected.  So the end user doesn't see the new/sync'd data automatically.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same problem, and solved by **configuring custom persistent store descriptions before calling loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:)**

```
container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "RubikClub")
// turn on persistent history tracking
let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(type(of: self).storeRemoteChange(_:)), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator)

container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
  if let error = error {
    fatalError("init core data error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}
container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

Comment: 18 months later, and solved at last!  The key here was that I need to to set the `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey` **BEFORE** calling `loadPersistentStores`.  I was doing it the other way around.  I have now updated the question to make it clear what I was doing wrong and to show how NOT to do it.  Doh!  Thanks.

Comment: If I could vote this up 100 times I would. Finally found this after trying numerous changes which just made my code more complicated without fixing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to require the `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` `object:` field to be `container.persistentStoreCoordinator` to work, which is in the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes.

Apple's example code at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/synchronizing_a_local_store_to_the_cloud uses `object: container` but doesn't work.

Comment: As you can see in my original code, I've already used the persistent store coordinator as the object in the notification observer call.  It is there in the commented out line, because it didn't work for me.  The uncommented version of the line is now being used as a catch-all, as it ought to work for any object that posts the notification, so should be even more reliable.  But in any case, I've tried it both ways (as well as the third/incorrect way of using the container, instead of the coordinator).  Unfortunately, it still does not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I just found out that it works fine in the TestFlight builds, but when directly built with Xcode, it does not. Have you tried that?

Also remember to listen for remote changes as outlined here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes

Comment: After deploying through TestFlight, the behaviour is just the same in my case.  Although the sync seems to take a lot longer, it does eventually happen.  But still no notification and no automatic updates in the UI.

Comment: There seem's to be something weird going on. I tested it on iPad, iPhone, and the Mac version of my example app. While things that I add on iPad and Mac sync fine to my iPhone and also fires the notification, it does not work the other way around or very infrequently. So, when I create something on my iPhone, it does not appear on the iPad or Mac without putting the apps in the background and then in the foreground again.

Comment: Update: I also reproduced this using Apple's sample app available here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/synchronizing_a_local_store_to_the_cloud. I just opened a technical support ticket and will wait for Apple's response.

Comment: @NicoReese What was the response from Apple? I have the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Listener:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRemoteChange), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: nil)
```

Should be added inside

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Here:
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRemoteChange), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: nil)
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe on view will disappear:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post.  Are you suggesting that simply moving the `addObserver()` call from `viewDidLoad()` to `viewWillAppear()` should solve the problem?  If so, I'd like to understand why.